# How can I deduplicate streams in KSQL?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a Kafka topic / stream that sometimes receives duplicates of events. How can I deduplicate the stream in KSQL?

Answer (score 1):

De-duplicating a stream is not currently possible in raw KSQL. You might be able to write a UDF for this.

Note that a table will only store the latest update (message) for a given key. Depending on your usecase, that could be helpful.